# Fuerte PCL/Flann Repo github.com/wg-debs no longer exist. Where was the source moved to?

Tags: ros, pcl, build-from-source, source, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

It has come to my attention that the "github.com/wg-debs" no longer exists.  This has been for some time the place where I pulled down the source for the packages in Fuerte, and the source for PCL and Flann.

Where do we get the source for PCL 1.5 and Flann that is needed by Fuerte?

I have found the other packages for Fuerte at the repo located in github.com/ros-gbp, but there does not seem to be a PCL 1.5 in there.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51382/fuerte-pcl/flann-repo-github.com/wg-debs-no-longer-exist.-where-was-the-source-moved-to?/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out where the repo was moved to:

flann: git://github.com/ros-gbp/flann-fuerte-release.git

pcl: git://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-fuerte-release.git

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[related](http://answers.ros.org/question/51317/ros-fuerte-on-ubuntu-from-source-checkout-error/)

---

Originally posted by [enodiesop](https://answers.ros.org/users/3856/enodiesop/) with karma: 41 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2